# Distribution of Y = max(X, alpha)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $X$ with density $f_X(x) = \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}, x > 0$. I have a transformation $Y=\max(X, \alpha)$ where $\alpha > 0$ and it is a constant. I need to find the distribution of Y.

I've tried to proceed using  the CDF of Y.

$$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \Bbb P \Bigl(\max\bigl(X, \alpha\bigr) \leq y\Bigr)$$

I rewrite the last event like this

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigl(\max\bigl(X, c\bigr) \leq y\Bigr) = \mathbb{P}\bigl(X \geq y\bigr)\cdot\mathbb{P}\bigl(\alpha \geq y\bigr)$$

but for me $\mathbb{P}(\alpha \geq y)$ does not make any sense.

What can I do to find the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: $\mathbb P\{\max\{X,\alpha \}\leq y\}=\mathbb P\{X\leq y, \alpha \leq y\}$ and $\mathbb P\{\alpha \leq y\}=\begin{cases}0&\alpha >y\\ 1&\alpha \leq y\end{cases}$ and it make sense.

Comment: The notation $\{Z\le z\}$ is a shorthand for $\{\omega\in\Omega: Z(\omega)\le z\}$. If $Z$ is a constant random variable with value $z_0$ the set is either $\Omega$ (if $z_0\le z$) or empty.

Answer (score 1):

a simple calculation shows that
\begin{align}
\Bbb P \Bigl(\max\bigl(X, \alpha \bigr) \leq y  \Bigr)& =  \\[2mm]
\Bbb P \Bigl(\max\bigl(X, \alpha \bigr) \leq y, \ X < \alpha  \Bigr)& +
\Bbb P \Bigl(\max\bigl(X, \alpha \bigr) \leq y, \ X \geq \alpha  \Bigr) = \\[2mm]
\Bbb P \Bigl(\alpha \leq y, \ X < \alpha  \Bigr)& +
\Bbb P \Bigl(X \leq y, \ X \geq \alpha  \Bigr) = \\[2mm]
\Bbb P \Bigl(\alpha \leq y, \ X < \alpha  \Bigr)& +
\Bbb P \Bigl(\alpha \leq X \leq y \Bigr) .
\end{align}
Now, if $\alpha >y$ then both terms in the last line are equal to zero. So we only need to further investigate the case where $\alpha \leq y$. If this is the case then we get using the continuity of the distribution of $X$
\begin{align}
\Bbb P \Bigl(\alpha \leq y, \ X < \alpha  \Bigr)& +
\Bbb P \Bigl(\alpha \leq X \leq y \Bigr) = F_X(\alpha) + F_X(y) - F_X(\alpha) = F_X(y).
\end{align}

To sum up
$$
F_Y(y) = \Bbb P (Y \leq y) = \begin{cases} F_X(y) =  \Bbb P (X \leq y), & \text{if} \ y < \alpha,\\
 0 , & \text{if} \ y \geq \alpha.\end{cases} 
$$